On npm install redux-devtools-extension
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!    C:\Users\Yoga\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-05-13T15_20_57_301Z-debug-0.log
PS: C:\Users\Yoga\Documents\Rough-Work
I tried to install redux-devtools-extension package. I was expecting a successful installation of the package.

Try running
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g npm@latest

and then retry to install redux-devtools-extensions
npm install redux-devtools-extension


I tried, but to no avail!
